# How to mutual/two-way authenticate with php curl?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

The website is saying "You are not authenticated with digital certificate, or possibly the connection time expired. Authenticate again with your digital certificate.".

I have gotten this message every time, so rather than connection time expiring, I think that my attempt of authenticating is just not working.

The way I am doing this is I start with just a pfx file, and a passphrase to open it. I make the pem certificate with openssl and the pfx.

Code:

```
<?php
$pfx_path = 'me.pfx';
$pfx_pass = 'foopass123';
$pfx_values = [];
openssl_pkcs12_read(file_get_contents($pfx_path), $pfx_values, $pfx_pass);
$cert_path = 'me.pem';
file_put_contents($cert_path, $pfx_values['cert'] . "\n" . $pfx_values['pkey']);
$postfields = 'field1=val1&field2=val2&field3=val3';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL           , 'https://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST          , true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    , $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT       , $cert_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Result of executing the code (showing just a quote of the HTML of $curl_result):

> You are not authenticated with digital certificate, or possibly the
>   connection time expired. Authenticate again with digital certificate.

By the way, `$curl_info['ssl_verify_result']` is 0, which I guess means that at least the server was correctly authenticated.

**EDIT:** removed `CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD` because it's not necessary, the pfx file was already open with the password, and its private and public key were put naked into `$cert_path`.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php#99979

Comment: It seems unlikely you need to set `CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD` since you've already pulled the info from PFX to PEM. And have you confirmed the PEM file is getting written?

Comment: @zod since the reply is coming from the server, they must already have the CA bundle set up correctly.

Comment: @zod, the code you linked helped me to figure out that I was missing headers that were specifically necessary in the site. I authenticated from a browser and copied the headers, then I finally got to authenticate, but I reused a session ID I got from the headers from the browser, and I don't know how obtain a session ID from php, I guess that's outside the scope of the question, so it's solved I guess.

Comment: @miken32 you are right, I didn't need the password for that reason.

Comment: Glad you got it working; sounds like it can be removed as typo/can't reproduce.

Comment: @miken32 thanks for caring :). I still think it's a valid question, since the answer to it is that different sites may need particular headers and/or cookies besides the certificate authentication. I posted an answer in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A header was necessary to achieve successful authentication on that specific site. The missing header was `Cookie: ...`, that contained specific fields, like for example a session ID (which you can get by logging in the website with cURL or simply as a user through a browser, you can copy and paste the cookie generated by the server).

You can specify the Cookie header with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,
    'foo=123;'
    . ' bar=456;'
    . ' SESSIONID=789;'
);
```

And alternatively you can specify it with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Cookie: foo=123;'
    . ' bar=456;'
    . ' SESSIONID=789;'
));
```

To look at this in a general way, and not as a problem limited to a specific site, notice that different sites will require different headers and cookies, as well as they may require none.

So if you want to do mutual authentication in a given site like a user does, make sure that you are using the correct headers and cookies in case it's needed.

Now, how to get a session ID with cURL, that depends on each site, and it's outside the scope of the question, but in general it's a matter of imitating with PHP the same operation that the user does in a browser, and it's probably done in a particular URL within the site, and not all site broad.

Comment: Normally a server gives you the cookie (through headers like `set-cookie`). which then the client sends back on further requests to same server. It should not be up the client to defined what to put in the cookie, by construction. Even further than that a server accepting an arbitrary cookie from the client (something he did not generate himself previously) is seriously vulnerable to a number of attacks...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek indeed, for security the session ID has to be generated by the server. In my case I had to find out an URL in the website that returns the session ID cookie in exchange of submitting a form with specific POST fields while simultaneously authenticating with client certificate, then I can use this session ID cookie to access different pages across the website until the session expires.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I clarified that part, I didn't mean to say that the server will accept any arbitrary cookie from the client, I hope it's clear now with my edit.